# How to keep modal inputs after a modal was closed?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modal-dialog

In the first modal user can basically add name and create name button will highlight and then user can add the name and the next modal will pop up which is the modal 2 below.

What I want to know is that how can I keep  the input from modal 1 which is the name example "Kiiiiii" that when user will click cancel in modal two it will go back to modal 1 and will keep the input and not erased ? and what is the right term to this ?

Just dont mind 2 different names from modal 1 and 2. Ideally it should be the same.

By the way I am using angular. Can anyone atleast provide sources related to this problme ? Thank you.

Any Idea ? Thank you.

I want that when the cancel button

[image: Modal 1]

This is the second modal

[image: Modal2]

Comment: Is your modal input form is related to one model in component.ts?

Comment: How are you closing the modal? Are you adding classes or you're using conditions? Based on what you have described, it sounds like you're also resetting the form when you cancel. So it's important to know your approach on how you're show/hiding your modal

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you can use local storage. You can create an object for a form, something like a ViewModel.

```
let obj = {
}
```

Then you handle all form actions. After filling the first modal you just save your data into that object.

```
obj.name = 'some field';
```

In this object you just store your data from the form. After clicking Add in the first modal you just stringify your object by using `JSON.stringify()` and save it into local storage, so your data is persistent. When you need your data you just read from the local storage and use `JSON.parse()` to convert the string into the object. After saving the data in modal 2 you can just erase your string with data from localstorage.

```
//useful methods
localStorage.setItem();
localStorage.getItem();
localStorage.removeItem();
```

Bibliography where you can find more information about JSON and localStorage:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: here is the html
 <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
            <mat-chip-list #chipList>
              <mat-chip *ngIf="hasSelectedName()"
                [selectable]="selectable"
                removable="true"
                (removed)="deselectName()"
              >
                {{form.controls.name.value.name}}
                <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
              </mat-chip>
            </mat-chip-list>

Answer (score 1):

Your modal should be integrated to an model such as

```
 export class EntryData{
        section:string="";
        name:string="";
        reprhrase:string="";
constructor(){}
    }
```

and u add this data to your component.ts

```
entryData:EntryData;
```

then in costructor f component initialize it

```
this.entryData=new EntryData();
```

in your html use your input two way such as

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="entryData.name" />
```

when u click the Create Name your model still be stored in backend. when u re-open your model it will be what u changed

Answer (score 0):

Several options are possible here,

- you could use a service in which you keep the global state values and then communicate the values to the different components while keeping the global state inside your service.
- you could use event emitters to pass the values between the components
- you could use input output , viewchild ...

there are other options too but if there suitable or not will also depend on how you implement these modals.

I would recommend reading

- https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
- https://angular.io/start/start-data

for more specific recommendations you should post your code :)